# Error 401 curl PUT php

Tags: php, web-services, curl

I am trying to consume a webservise with curl through PUT, but it return me an error 401. Could be by the content header? if I put 0, it return me 401. My code:

```
$data = array(
            'codigo' => $codigo,
            'nombre' => $nombre,
            'descripcion' => $descripcion,
            'fecha_inicio' => $fecha_inicio,
            'fecha_fin' => $fecha_fin,
            'dmañana' => $dmaniana,
            'hmañana' => $hmaniana,
            'dtarde' => $dtarde,
            'htarde' => $htarde,
            'objetivo' => $objetivo,
            'propietario' => $propietario,
            'derechos' => $derechos,
            'lista' => $lista,
            'argumentario' => $argumentario
    );


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.'?'.http_build_query($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length: 0', "TokenSession: ".$token));
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: A 401 error is telling you that you're not authorised to make your request to the server. Does the server you're trying to query require authentication?

Comment: Also - why set `Content-Length: 0` when you are wanting to use the PUT method to pass data?

Comment: Yes, I need to pass a token by the header generated in other webservices

Comment: If I put for exmaple curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length: '.strlen(http_build_query($data)), "TokenSession: ".$token)); It return me the same error 401

Comment: The issue is most likely then that you're not authenticated correctly...as the error is telling you.